# wordpress commenting system

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to use wordpress's commenting system. Their documentation is very confusing and it is kind of a pain to work with. I am trying to use the same commenting system they have on the default twentytwelve theme. It seems to be the way I want it. But even when using the same code they have I do not get a list of previous comment.

This is my comments.php

```
if ( post_password_required() )
    return;
?>

<div id="comments" class="comments-area">

    <?php // You can start editing here -- including this comment! ?>

    <?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
        <h2 class="comments-title">
            <?php
                printf( _n( 'One thought on &ldquo;%2$s&rdquo;', '%1$s thoughts on &ldquo;%2$s&rdquo;', get_comments_number(), 'dogcompany' ),
                    number_format_i18n( get_comments_number() ), '<span>' . get_the_title() . '</span>' );
            ?>
        </h2>

        <ol class="commentlist">
            <?php wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'dogcompany_comment', 'style' => 'ol' ) ); ?>
        </ol><!-- .commentlist -->

        <?php if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) : // are there comments to navigate through ?>
        <div id="comment-nav-below" class="navigation" role="navigation">
            <h1 class="assistive-text section-heading"><?php _e( 'Comment navigation', 'dogcompany' ); ?></h1>
            <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_comments_link( __( '&larr; Older Comments', 'dogcompany' ) ); ?></div>
            <div class="nav-next"><?php next_comments_link( __( 'Newer Comments &rarr;', 'dogcompany' ) ); ?></div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; // check for comment navigation ?>

        <?php
        /* If there are no comments and comments are closed, let's leave a note.
         * But we only want the note on posts and pages that had comments in the first place.
         */
        if ( ! comments_open() && get_comments_number() ) : ?>
        <p class="nocomments"><?php _e( 'Comments are closed.' , 'dogcompany' ); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endif; // have_comments() ?>

    <?php comment_form(); ?>

</div><!-- #comments .comments-area -->
```

This is function.php

```
<?php
function dogcompany_setup(){

// Adds RSS feed links to <head> for posts and comments.
add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );

}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'dogcompany_setup' );
function dogcompany_scripts_styles() {
    global $wp_styles;

    /*
     * Adds JavaScript to pages with the comment form to support
     * sites with threaded comments (when in use).
     */
    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) )
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );

        $protocol = is_ssl() ? 'https' : 'http';
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dogcompany_scripts_styles' );
/*remove admin bar */
show_admin_bar(false);



if ( ! function_exists( 'dogcompany_comment' ) ) :
/**
 * Template for comments and pingbacks.
 *
 * To override this walker in a child theme without modifying the comments template
 * simply create your own dogcompany_comment(), and that function will be used instead.
 *
 * Used as a callback by wp_list_comments() for displaying the comments.
 *
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */
function dogcompany_comment( $comment, $args, $depth ) {
    $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;
    switch ( $comment->comment_type ) :
        case 'pingback' :
        case 'trackback' :
        // Display trackbacks differently than normal comments.
    ?>
    <li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
        <p><?php _e( 'Pingback:', 'dogcompany' ); ?> <?php comment_author_link(); ?> <?php edit_comment_link( __( '(Edit)', 'dogcompany' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?></p>
    <?php
            break;
        default :
        // Proceed with normal comments.
        global $post;
    ?>
    <li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="li-comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
        <article id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>" class="comment">
            <header class="comment-meta comment-author vcard">
                <?php
                    echo get_avatar( $comment, 44 );
                    printf( '<cite class="fn">%1$s %2$s</cite>',
                        get_comment_author_link(),
                        // If current post author is also comment author, make it known visually.
                        ( $comment->user_id === $post->post_author ) ? '<span> ' . __( 'Post author', 'dogcompany' ) . '</span>' : ''
                    );
                    printf( '<a href="%1$s"><time datetime="%2$s">%3$s</time></a>',
                        esc_url( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ) ),
                        get_comment_time( 'c' ),
                        /* translators: 1: date, 2: time */
                        sprintf( __( '%1$s at %2$s', 'dogcompany' ), get_comment_date(), get_comment_time() )
                    );
                ?>
            </header><!-- .comment-meta -->

            <?php if ( '0' == $comment->comment_approved ) : ?>
                <p class="comment-awaiting-moderation"><?php _e( 'Your comment is awaiting moderation.', 'dogcompany' ); ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <section class="comment-content comment">
                <?php comment_text(); ?>
                <?php edit_comment_link( __( 'Edit', 'dogcompany' ), '<p class="edit-link">', '</p>' ); ?>
            </section><!-- .comment-content -->

            <div class="reply">
                <?php comment_reply_link( array_merge( $args, array( 'reply_text' => __( 'Reply', 'dogcompany' ), 'after' => ' <span>&darr;</span>', 'depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'] ) ) ); ?>
            </div><!-- .reply -->
        </article><!-- #comment-## -->
    <?php
        break;
    endswitch; // end comment_type check
}
endif;

if ( ! function_exists( 'dogcompany_entry_meta' ) ) :
/**
 * Prints HTML with meta information for current post: categories, tags, permalink, author, and date.
 *
 * Create your own dogcompany_entry_meta() to override in a child theme.
 *
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */
function dogcompany_entry_meta() {
    // Translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma.
    $categories_list = get_the_category_list( __( ', ', 'dogcompany' ) );

    // Translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma.
    $tag_list = get_the_tag_list( '', __( ', ', 'dogcompany' ) );

    $date = sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date" datetime="%3$s">%4$s</time></a>',
        esc_url( get_permalink() ),
        esc_attr( get_the_time() ),
        esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
        esc_html( get_the_date() )
    );

    $author = sprintf( '<span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="author">%3$s</a></span>',
        esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ),
        esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all posts by %s', 'dogcompany' ), get_the_author() ) ),
        get_the_author()
    );

    // Translators: 1 is category, 2 is tag, 3 is the date and 4 is the author's name.
    if ( $tag_list ) {
        $utility_text = __( 'This entry was posted in %1$s and tagged %2$s on %3$s<span class="by-author"> by %4$s</span>.', 'dogcompany' );
    } elseif ( $categories_list ) {
        $utility_text = __( 'This entry was posted in %1$s on %3$s<span class="by-author"> by %4$s</span>.', 'dogcompany' );
    } else {
        $utility_text = __( 'This entry was posted on %3$s<span class="by-author"> by %4$s</span>.', 'dogcompany' );
    }

    printf(
        $utility_text,
        $categories_list,
        $tag_list,
        $date,
        $author
    );
}
endif;
```

Thank you,

Comment: Im not sure which part is the problem in function but i tried shortening it a bit

Answer (score -1):

I don't know exactly where you are mistaken. Use new wordpress pack comments.php and functions.php codes. I think it will be solve your problem.

Comment: if you mean copying and pasting what they have on their theme. Thats essentially what I did. I also tried copying it word for word with no modification and nothing was working. I am not sure what you mean by wordpress's new pack comments.php and function.php